# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException, Mule 4.3, Anypoint studio 7.8

Tags: java, xml, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am new to Mulesoft(using Mule 4.3ee and Anypoint Studio 7.8). I added a Database Select tool. I configured with the Oracle database. The Test connection is successful and it worked fetching the records successfully. Later I added a new Configuration file to the same project for Delete. I added Database Delete tool and when trying torun the project, I get **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException** I tried creating new Database COnfig file and tried to run. Still I am getting the same error. If I create a new Mule projecrt and re-create the flow, it is working fine. I tired many solutions suggested in Stackoverflow like adding new dependencies, adding mule references like mule-dbserver.xsd and restarting tooling instances. Nothing worked. Please help me resolve this issue.

Find below the error msg I am getting:

```
    Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: There were '7' errors while parsing the given file 'emp-sapi2.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'responseStreamingMode' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'outputMimeType' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'primaryNodeOnly' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'path' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'outputEncoding' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'config-ref' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 321; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'allowedMethods' is not allowed to appear in element 'http:listener-config'.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing details, however for an XML error it would be important to add the XML configurations, as text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason that configurations files, source code should be text and not images.

Answer (score 0):

The error is unrelated to the Database connector. It says that the XML parser can not understand some attributes of the HTTP Listener configuration. If it was working before it is possible that when editing the database namespace you accidentally left out the http namespace. It is strange because it is only complaining of the attributes, not of the namespace itself. Maybe you pointed the http namespace to the wrong schema?

Usually if you are using the graphical view Studio takes care of namespaces for you.